# routing traffic between two vpn

Tags: networking, 20.04, vpn, openconnect

I have two VPNs. one is Openconnect for my company sites and the other is Windscribe.
I need only to pass traffic of the company's sites Ips, starting with 172 from Openconnect and any others Ips to Windscribe. how can I do this?